# In a modification flow, should I allow user to delete the form while editing?

Tags: navigation, deletion

In my case, normally the flow is to first search and then modify/view/delete from the search result list.

'Modify' and 'View' need to open a new page as there is further information in the details.

The system allows the user to delete directly from search result list and view detail page.

Due to the access right control, modify / view / delete will applied to different types of user.

For those users that only have access of delete and modify, should I allow user to delete directly in the modify detail page? It seems it will reduce the switch between search result page and modify page. But I am unsure whether it is reasonable to allow the user to delete while editing in modification page?

Comment: Sometimes I may want to recreate something from scratch instead of editing all the fields and often this comes to my mind while I'm editing something :) so it's pretty OK to put Delete at the Edit screen I think.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your detail page represents that entity you want to represent. It should have everything you can do with that entity. That screen is the super-set of whatever functions you have on that entity.

Having an operation on search result screen is a shortcut which you are offering. This is a good thing. This enhances usability by offering an option to quickly take an action on the result of the search. Please note that this extra function available on search is a bonus. It should not be exclusively present on that screen. It should be in detail, and it *can* be on the search.

Answer (score -1):

It's not normal, I don't have research to support this though, when you are editing a form and you delete it what happens next? Do you get redirected to the list page? What happens if you already had some fields edited before you pressed delete? I personally don't think it's a great idea

Comment: I find your reasoning rather weak. As merqri points out, the detail screen represents an entity (whether in edit-mode or not) and deleting that entity is a normal operation and therefore belongs there. There should of course be a prompt to the user before removing it irreversibly (*"Delete? Unsaved changes will be lost."*). Going back to the list page seems sensible, although there are other patterns around. Google's Gmail app allows to configure the behavior, whether you want it to take you back to overview, or go to next / previous email.

Comment: Deleting an entity is not the problem here, where you delete it is the problem i'ts like deleting an open document on windows, it will never allow you to do that because it might cause inconsistencies the usual parten is to delete an entity from a list of entities, not while opening it. It's counter intuitive

Comment: You can delete an opened file on Windows unless the application using it requested a type of access that prevents it. You can test that with Notepad for instance. After removing the file, you will be able to save the file again (it's still in memory). I can't see any inconsistence. You can also close an unsaved Word document (which can be seen as object), while the document is in edit mode and you being on object level. Google Photos let's you delete an image while it is displayed fullscreen (just like any of the other operations like share, edit, info). All you offered are groundless claims.

Comment: @CoDEmanX try what you told me to try with notepad with Excel, you won't be able to delete an open spreadshit with excel... so what do you mean my claims are groundless?

Comment: I falsified your claim that a document could **never** be deleted while it's opened. One could see Notepad as the exception to the rule, but the point is  there are prominent exceptions and deleting while on object level is apparently not an issue. Or would you call e.g. Google Photos broken?

Comment: It's just not a good UX, like I pointed out there is no "standard flow" to follow after deleting an active object, which might confuse the user

Comment: Show me research on this or the hordes of confused users of apps which do allow the deletion while on object level. So far it's only your opinion against my examples apparently proving you wrong… IMO there's a reasonable flow.